# Non guarded routes in angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I want to know how to find out all the routes which are not protected with a guard in angular 2? I know that adding this property "canActivate : [myGuard]" in routes will call the canActivate method of my guard. But how to make a list of all the routes which don't have this property?

Comment: I don't get it, if you can access your **appRoutes** array what's the impediment to get the routers you need ?

Comment: @Hosar - I need to access this information in a different module(core module). This core module has a guard and every time a protected route is hit, I get a callback in the canActivate but I don't know how many routes are unguarded/unprotected.

Answer (score 1):

I would have pass a key in the path data telling me whether it is guarded or not if i were you. Like below.

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'crisis-center', component: CrisisListComponent , canActivate: [YourCanActivateClass] },
  { path: 'hero/:id',      component: HeroDetailComponent, canActivate: [YourCanActivateClass] },
  {
    path: 'heroes',
    component: HeroListComponent,
    data: { isGuaded: false }
  },
];
```

And in your individual component you can

```
constructor(route: ActivatedRoute) {
    isGuaded= this.route.snapshot.data['isGuaded'];

  if(isGuaded === false) {
   //Your login here
  }
}
```

This is another way.

Comment: -Thanks for your answer. I also thought about this approach, the issue is that if I have 15 routes and only 2 are guarded and rest are not, I will end up adding isGuard=false to remaining 13. I was looking for a better approach.